# Angular ng-repeat filter on nested array in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to applay a filter in my ng-repeat based on a nested array. The object that is used for the ng-repeat:

**Updated**

master_array:

```
   {
  "0": {
    "Employee_Id": "hni",
    "comptencies": [
      {
        "Title": "Bunker Knowledge",
        "Level": 1
      },
      {
        "Title": "Bunker Knowledge",
        "Level": 3
      },
      {
        "Title": "IT Compliance",
        "Level": 2
      },
      {
        "Title": "Bunker Knowledge",
        "Level": 5
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.myFilter = {
    competencyTitle : ""
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label>Competencies
<select ng-model="myFilter.competencyTitle" ng-options="item.Title for item in competencies_list"></select>
</label>


<tr ng-repeat="item in master_array | filter: { competencies: [{ Competency.Title: myFilter.competencyTitle }] }">
```

The above doesn't work.

**Case**

I have a list of employees and each employee has an id and array of competencies attached. Each item in this array has a comptency array attached, which holds the title an id of the competency. What I want is to be able to filter out employees with specific competencies.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are referring to competencies_list but it should be competencies.

Comment: The `competencies_list` is used to create select options. The values are identical to those inside the `master_array`, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You probably have to adapt it to your specific code:

The main idea is this: **filter: {  $: {Title: myFilter.competencyTitle.Title}  }**

The $ selects any element whose child is Title.

html

```
<label>Competencies {{myFilter.competencyTitle.Title}}
    <select ng-model="myFilter.competencyTitle" ng-options="item.Title for item in competencies_list"></select>
</label>


<p ng-repeat="item in master_array | filter: {  $: {Title: myFilter.competencyTitle.Title}  }">{{item.employee_id}} {{item.competencies}}    </p>
```

js - this is the model is used, I'm not sure if this reflects your actual model.

```
$scope.competencies_list = [{Title : "Math"},{Title : "English"},{Title : "Spanish"}];

$scope.master_array = 
[
    {         
        employee_id: "hni",         
        competencies:
            [
                {Title : "Math", "Level": 1},
                {Title : "English", "Level": 2}           
            ]
    }, 
    {
        employee_id: "xyz",         
        competencies:
            [
                {Title : "Spanish", "Level": 3},
                {Title : "English", "Level": 5}           
            ]
    }
];

$scope.myFilter = {
    competencyTitle : ""
};
```

Comment: The "object" you posted above is not valid json and not javascript to my understanding.

Comment: I will edit the "object" to represent its real representation. It is valid in my production code. This one was just for displaying the structure. However i get an error from your code: `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}`

Comment: "This error occurs when filter is not used with an array". Make sure master_array is an array. Can you post the structure of master_array?

Comment: I have updated the object in the op. Also made some small changes to the structure.

Comment: What is the structure of master_array? The error message says it is not a real array. Can you post it?

Comment: I have added the master_array to the original post.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your master_array is not an array! An array looks like this: master_array = [x, y, z] but you have master_array = { 0: x, 1: y, 2: z}. You need to make this a real array! I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You were right. I think I am almost there. The filter now filters out employees without any competencies, but not on the specific competency.

Comment: Never mind the last comment. You were spot on! Thanks